# Can't add a UIViewController subclass to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutabledictionary

I wan't to add a subclass of UIViewController to a NSMutableDictionary which should be no problem since UIViewController is a NSObject.

This is my code:

```
NSArray *requestingPathes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
requestingPair = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:requestingPathes, dele, nil];
```

The app crashes when the delegate "dele" (which happens to be the mentioned subclass) is used to initialize the Dictionary "requestingPair".

The error is:

```
-[MainViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7446b30
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MainViewController copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7446b30
```

0x7446b30 is the address of the subclass "MainViewController.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-initWithObjectsAndKeys:` expects a list of objects and keys, in that order—alternating object, key, object, key, nil. What you’re doing is trying to give it your `dele` object as a key from which the value `requestingPathes` can be retrieved; NSDictionary objects copy their keys when you set them, and your view controller doesn’t support being copied, so that’s failing. Presumably what you want to do is something more like this:

```
requestingPair = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:requestingPathes, @"paths", dele, @"delegate", nil];
```

You can then retrieve the delegate object by calling `[requestingPair objectForKey:@"delegate"]` and the paths with `[requestPair objectForKey:@"paths"]`.

Comment: The delegate must be they key. There is a list of delegates each associated with an Array of indexPathes. I didn't know the key is copied. So I store the address of the delegate as NSNumber.

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary key must conform to the NSCopying protocol, which UIViewController (and your MainViewController) doesn't.

Do you want dele to be the key or the value? It's currently the key.